# Passing forwarding references to thread wrapper class

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Let's take a look at the concrete functions first:

```
void boo1 () { std::cout << "boo1\n"; }
void boo2 (std::string) { std::cout << "boo2\n"; }

struct X {
    void boo3 () { std::cout << "boo3\n"; }
    void boo4 (std::string) { std::cout << "boo4\n"; }
};
```

I want those functions to be executed with some "guard" function, which does exception protection (explanation below). So, I have written two functions one for free functions and the other for member functions:

```
template <typename C, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value, void>::type
foo (C&& c, Args&&... args) {
    std::cout << "not memfun\n";
    c (std::forward<Args> (args)...);
}

template <typename C, typename T, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value, void>::type
foo (C&& c, T* o, Args&&... args) {
    std::cout << "memfun\n";
    (o->*c) (std::forward<Args> (args)...);
}
```

And now I want to execute `boo1()`, `boo2()`, `X::boo3()` and `X::boo4()` in new threads but with "protection" used by `foo()` functions. So, without any problem I can do this with:

```
X x;
std::thread th1 {&foo<void (*) ()>, &boo1};
std::thread th2 {&foo<void (*) (std::string), std::string>, &boo2, "Hello"};
std::thread th3 {&foo<void (X::*) (), X>, &X::boo3, &x};
std::thread th4 {&foo<void (X::*) (std::string), X, std::string>, &X::boo4, &x, "Hello"};
```

So, going one step further I have written thread wrapper class to stop using explicitly `std::join()` or `std::detach()`.
Insted one of them is invoked when destructor is in action. For the simplicity of this example I have only used one of them.
So, the code looks like this:

```
class Th {
public:
    template <typename C, 
              typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value, void>::type,
              typename... Args>
    Th (C&& c, Args... args) // (X)
    : t {foo<C, Args...>, std::forward<C> (c), std::forward<Args> (args)...} {}

    template <typename C,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value, void>::type,
              typename T,
              typename... Args>
    Th (C&& c, T* o, Args... args) // (Y)
    : t { foo<C, T, Args...>, std::forward<C> (c), o, std::forward<Args> (args)...} {}


    ~Th () { t.join (); }

private:
    std::thread t;
};
```

And with this implementation there is no problem, the following usage cases:

```
X x;
Th h1 {&boo1};
Th h2 {&boo2, "Hello"};
Th h3 {&X::boo3, &x};
Th h4 {&X::boo4, &x, "Hello"};
```

work as excepcted. However there is one flaw here - no perfect forwarding. If I change in `(X)` and `(Y)` `Args...` to `Args&&...` which is desired,
the code does not compile with some errors, one of them is:

```
error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(void (*)(std::basic_string<char>), const char*))(void (*&&)(std::basic_string<char>), const char (&)[6])>’
```

which if I understand it correctly, `std::bind()` in `std::thread` constructor can not do it's job, or correct me if I am wrong.

My question is: **what can I do to take advantage of perfect forwarding in this case?**

Compiler used to compile this was GCC 4.8.1.

**Promised explanation**: I want `foo()` functions to surround call to `c()` with `try` and `catch` to make sure that the exception is catched, process this information in some kind of logging mechanism, and rethrow the exception if needed with the transparency to the user of `Th` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When passing lvalue references to `std::thread`, you need to wrap them in `std::reference_wrapper`. For example, you can do it in the following way:

```
namespace detail
{

template<typename T>
std::reference_wrapper<T> forward_to_thread(T& t, std::true_type) {
    return std::ref(t);
}

template<typename T>
T&& forward_to_thread(T&& t, std::false_type) {
    return std::move(t);
}

}

template<typename T>
auto forward_to_thread(T&& t)
    -> decltype(detail::forward_to_thread(std::forward<T>(t), std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{}))
{
    return detail::forward_to_thread(std::forward<T>(t), std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{});
}
```

Then you just replace `std::forward` calls to `forward_to_thread` in `thread` initialization:

```
class Th {
public:
    template <typename C,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<!std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value, void>::type,
              typename... Args>
    Th (C&& c, Args&&... args) // (X)
    : t {foo<C, Args...>, std::forward<C> (c), forward_to_thread<Args> (std::forward<Args>(args))...} {}

    template <typename C,
              typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_member_function_pointer<C>::value, void>::type,
              typename T,
              typename... Args>
    Th (C&& c, T* o, Args&&... args) // (Y)
    : t { foo<C, T, Args...>, std::forward<C> (c), o, forward_to_thread<Args> (std::forward<Args>(args))...} {}


    ~Th () { t.join (); }

private:
    std::thread t;
};
```

This does work with gcc 4.8.2 [[link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vRyQxhvYaSrFgeqD)]

If you can use a newer compiler, consider using [`std::invoke`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) (C++17) for more succint and readable code (i.e. [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0tnxH7cZjr1vVixE)).

Comment: Interesting. This fails to compile if I run it with `std::string("Hello")` instead of with plain `"Hello"` in `h2` and `h4`. The error is `no known conversion from 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> &&' for 1st argument auto forward_to_thread(T&& t)` (`clang 5.0`).

Comment: The arguments of `forward_to_thread` should be forwarded as well, fixed. Thanks.